# Mark privileged views and action popups with the privilege that unlocked it

Tags: feature-request, privileges

Could we have a small marker somewhere on privilege-restricted pages and popups that shows what privilege unlocks it?

I'm mostly active on one site, and I have a lot of rep there. I've had it long enough that new privileges and features have come into being that I've never not had. I can't remember and often can't figure out what other users can see or do, and the privilege help pages don't keep up with all the little details.

For example, today I responded to a comment on a meta post that they could just see for themselves by looking at the Close Review Queue's history. Oops, turns out that's a 10k privilege? I don't know, I just mod here! I never didn't have the queue history access privilege to even know that it was a privilege-restricted feature, since it started existing after I had the privilege.

It would be really, really useful to have a small marker somewhere on a page with the privilege that grants access to what I'm looking at. Just a discreet “10k” bubble in the corner of a dialogue box or the page. The data is there — this view is only being offered because my rep was checked against that privilege threshold — so it would be useful to be shown that threshold directly.

(I expect that the graphic design with actually be slightly more effort. But please! I feel like Marie Antoinette saying “let them eat cake”, sitting on my literal pile of virtual privilege, when they really can't use these features I take for granted.)